# Dirty parallelisation of Python program

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I've got a program that loads 2600 images in a loop, does some processing and returns a value. Pseudo code:

```
for file in files:
  codes[file] = my_function(file)
return codes
```

The problem is - this process takes around 20-30 minutes, and seems to only use one CPU core. I'm looking for a quick and dirty way to run this across more cores, perhaps by splitting the list in two. I've read a bunch about Python and it's problems/solutions, but I can't figure what to do next. How do I do this?

FYI Using Python 2.7 on 2009 Macbook Pro (Core 2 Duo) w/ Numpy Scipy Scikit-image & OpenCV.

Comment: If you process all images completely independently, then create two scripts, both processing a set of 1300 images. Start the scripts one after another, and then you should have one python interpreter running on each core. (But +1 for Patrick's solution, which is really the clean one.)

Comment: We'll write up this solution in the scikit-image user guide for the next release.

Comment: if you want to have it really dirty, parallelise in bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is with `multiprocessing`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool() as p:
    all_codes = p.map(my_function, files)
return {f:code for code, f in zip(all_codes, files)}
```

Comment: Hi Patrick! Many thanks, this looks great! Two questions- can you kindly explain the last line, and 2 do I need to explicitly call p.start() to kick it off?

Comment: The last line is a dictionary comprehension to return things in the same format you had in your question (using the file handle as a key). There's no need to call `p.start()` -- using `p.map` gets Python to intelligently chunk out work to processes as they finish what they're doing.

Comment: This produced more than 100% speedup. Thank-you! :)

Comment: One quick question, your code didn't work as expected (AttributeError on with line); I did this: 
p=Pool()
all_codes = p.map(my_function, items)

Are they equivalent or did I miss something?

Comment: You have the `import` line, too? And there's something in scope named `items`?